# Why does a function declared and included using header file show as undefined?

Tags: c

I have the following code in my files and all of these are in the same directory:

readMake.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_make.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    printSomething();
}
```

printer.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int printSomething(){
    printf("printed\n");
    return 1;
}
```

my_make.h:

```
int printSomething();
```

However, when I try to compile and run my code, I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/11/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/prob1.dir/readMake.c.o: in function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/harsh/OneDrive/Documents/CSC352/assg9/prob1/readMake.c:5: undefined reference to `printSomething'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/prob1.dir/build.make:93: prob1.exe] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/prob1.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:90: CMakeFiles/prob1.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:124: prob1] Error 2
```

My IDE shows the proper signature of the printSignature function and where it is declared in the header file when I hover over the call in main, but the compilation doesn't seem to be working. Why is this happening  and how can I resolve this?

Comment: You don't show your link command, but most likely you're simply not including printer.c in the link (its not in the dependencies of the target in CMakefile.txt), so the function is undefined.

Comment: @ChrisDodd was using the run button in the IDE and assumed that the makefile would be updated automatically. I am using CLion, is there a way I can fix the makefile? it seems rather big and unreadable.

Comment: I assumed you were using cmake as your error message refers to CMakeFiles -- if not, you need to figure out how to tell your IDE or whatever you are using to include printer.c in the build.

Comment: Figured it out and posted an answer. Thanks for the help, if you handn't pointed out that the mistake was in the makefile, I would not have known how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution specific to CLion, unloading the CMakeLists.txt file and then creating a new one seems to resolve the issue.

I had to do 'Tools>CMake>Unload'

and then create a new CMakeLists.txt file which was automatically done by clicking an option appearing at the top of the window and selecting all of the files from a list of checkboxes.

Comment: A header file declares the function. You must include the definition of the function when linking the complete program (you need to link multiple object files). Note that your `printer.c` file should also include `my_make.h`. Also note that although you declare the function, you do not specify a prototype. It could be called with any number of arguments (including zero) of any type. You should be explicit. For example — `extern int printSomething(void);` — where the `extern` is optional (but I prefer to see it) and the `(void)` is mandatory to state that the function takes no arguments at all.